How to know a device support OpenXR or not?
My VR application was developed by OpenXR API, it can run in Meta Quest, Pico, HTC vive series those VR devices very well, now I want to porting it to mobile device with Google cardboard SDK, so I need to know the device whether it has openXR or not, is there have a way to do that? Currently I use device model to distinguish them.

Here's a code example in C++ using OpenXR that demonstrates how to check for OpenXR support on a device:
#include <openxr/openxr.h>
#include <iostream>

bool isOpenXRSupported() {
    // Initialize OpenXR
    XrInstance instance = XR_NULL_HANDLE;
    XrInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo = {XR_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO};
    strcpy(instanceCreateInfo.applicationInfo.applicationName, "OpenXR Checker");
    instanceCreateInfo.applicationInfo.apiVersion = XR_CURRENT_API_VERSION;

    XrResult result = xrCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, &instance);
    if (XR_FAILED(result)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create OpenXR instance." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Query the available extensions
    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    result = xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, 0, &extensionCount, nullptr);
    if (XR_FAILED(result)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to enumerate OpenXR extensions." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::vector<XrExtensionProperties> extensions(extensionCount, {XR_TYPE_EXTENSION_PROPERTIES});
    result = xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, extensionCount, &extensionCount, extensions.data());
    if (XR_FAILED(result)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to enumerate OpenXR extensions." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Check for specific extensions if needed
    bool isSupported = true;
    for (const auto& ext : extensions) {
        std::cout << "Available extension: " << ext.extensionName << std::endl;
        // Add any specific extension checks if necessary
    }

    // Clean up
    xrDestroyInstance(instance);

    return isSupported;
}

int main() {
    if (isOpenXRSupported()) {
        std::cout << "OpenXR is supported on this device." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "OpenXR is not supported on this device." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


@Bob Smith I used the above codes to detect supporting OpenXR or not, it works.
